# modelcontainer update method

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

Heloo everyone - 
I have this quiz question to see if there is anything wrong with this method, I solved the other ones but I can't see anything wrong with this method. Can you guys spot something wrong in this method?

```
private void UpdateUsers(List<string> users) 
    {
 foreach (var user in users) 
    { 
    ModelContainer DBContext = new ModelContainer(); 
    var u = from q in DBContext.Users 
    where q.Name == user 
    select q; 
    u.IsActive = true;
     DBContext.SaveChanges();
     } 
    }
```

Thanks in advance, Laziale

Comment: Do you have to make the ModelContainer object for every iteration?

Comment: this is everything what is given in the quiz :) Thanks

Comment: Laziale, please be sure to mark an answer as correct if it answered your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing this:

```
private void UpdateUsers(List<string> users) 
{
    using(DBContext context = new DBContext("myConnectionString"))
    {
        foreach (var user in users) 
        {
            var u = from q in DBContext.Users
                where q.Name == user 
                select q; 
            u.IsActive = true;
        } 
    }
}
```

With the `using` statement, the DBContext should automatically save itself.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a ModelContainer instance for every iteration and that looks dodgy.

I would do something like:

```
using(ModelContainer DBContext = new ModelContainer())
{

    foreach (var user in users) 
    { 
        var u = (from q in DBContext.Users 
         where q.Name == user 
         select q).FirstOrDefault(); 

        if(u!=null)
        {
            u.IsActive = true;
        }
  }
  DBContext.SaveChanges(); //Save changes once, and not per user. Unless you can but I doubt it.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be `select q.FirstOrDefault();` or the `var u` will be an `IEnumerable`, no?

Comment: That, and you don't need to reinstantiate ModelContainer for each user.